# i tried to start a service ( playing music) from an activity but it is not working at all can anyone i am using kotlin below is my code

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I tried to start a service (playing music from an activity) but when pressed on start button on the activity Ui no sound heard totally silent I don't know where is the problem in the below code ,the service already added in the manifest file

class MyService : Service() {

```
lateinit var  mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Log.i("Service","service Created")
    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.music2)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.i("Service","service Destroyed")
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying){
        mediaPlayer.stop()
        mediaPlayer.release()
    }
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.i("Service","service Started")
    if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying)
        mediaPlayer.start()
    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
    TODO("Return the communication channel to the service.")
}
```

}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var startBtn:Button
lateinit var stopBtn:Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

override fun onCreateView(name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs)
    Log.i("Service","activityCreated")
    startBtn=findViewById(R.id.startBtn)
    stopBtn=findViewById(R.id.stopBtn)
    startBtn.setOnClickListener {
    val intent=Intent(context,MyService::class.java)
        if(context!=null)
         context.startService(intent)


    }

    stopBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent=Intent(context,MyService::class.java)
        stopService(intent)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and place code in `code` blocks properly.

Comment: "it is not working" -- what does this mean? What are your specific symptoms?

Comment: I edited the problem I mean when pressed on start button on the activity Ui no sound heard totally silent

Comment: This is just a thought.. I test all of my apps on a physical device. The code looks right other than stuff missing like volume and so forth. However, if your using an emulator sometimes the sound won't play. I found this out because sound was disabled in the emulator. I would check sound settings in emulator. If that doesn't work try using a code to set the volume.

Comment: I think you must use startforgoundservice
And notify notification on service